# Setting dropdown in iPAD

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4

I was looking at an app screenshot and was impressed with its setting options for iPAD. See screenshot

[image]

Can anyone tell me how is this setting drop implemented for iPAD? I usually take the user to a brand new page/view controller where I define a static table and options in it. I don't know how to implement it within the same view controller like the way they have it. Is there any example/sample code available? or steps of how to create one in Xcode 4.0? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a `UIPopoverController`. Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html), it's really pretty easy to create one. Essentially, you just put a normal view controller into it and present it from either a rectangle or a toolbar button. If your view controller doesn't fill the entire screen height, you should also set its `contentSizeForViewInPopover` property.

Comment: So in the above picture, did they create a static table and then defined cells and radial on/off buttons all with writing code? I usually use Xcode drag and drop to create all the above but I guess I will have to code for it in order to make it work as a UIPopoverController.

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong but I can create a brand new UITableViewController, define all my cells and layout in xib using xcode drag/drop etc and then call that tablecontroller in my uipopovercontroller and it will display everything that I had defined in my UITableViewController with minimal code. That's what I gathered from this example here ... http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/using-popoverview-ipad-app-development

Comment: Sam, you gotta read the documentation of how to use UIPopoverController. A UIPopoverController is unique to iPad and it's just a container where you can put whatever controllers inside. So what you do is just create a normal view, and for your setting button tap up inside IBAction fuction, create a UIPopoverController by using -initWithContentViewController: to point to the view you created, call -presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated() and then you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial) will help you i think. There is a sample to learn how to.
Also there is a video tutorial [here](http://ulapp.us/ipad-app-video-ipad-app-tutorial-uipopovercontroller/).